# Are there any autocompletion input tools for English? Except default TextEdit app

Tags: mac, performance

I'm a Mac user who is a Japanese. I usually type Japanese using Google IME  which enables me to type it with predictive texts so that we can type it faster.

[image]

Google IME

http://www.google.co.jp/ime/

In terms of English, I can't find good tools such as IME and a text editor. Does anyone know of one?

Comment: Google IME is a input method, the Textedit is a editor. what are you talking about?

Comment: Sorry for my vague question.I prefer to use autocompletion as IME rather than a text editor.I'm gonna change the title of this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question may have already been answered by [How to setup predictive text (autocomplete) on Mac?](https://superuser.com/questions/792850/how-to-setup-predictive-text-autocomplete-on-mac), which states:

> The closest things I've found to what you are looking for are this
>   text editor experiment that you have to compile yourself
>
> http://alvinalexander.com/java/type-ahead-continuous-predictive-text-editor-auto-complete
>
> And this Chrome extension for Gmail https://complete.li
>
> Both would require you to type in their respective places and then
>   paste into your application of choice, but I haven't found anything
>   that works systemwide.

However, just to complete the answer, there is a IME type method built into **TextEdit**, that can be activated by hitting the *ESCAPE* key, so if you type "beg" then the system will bring up a selection of words beginning with "beg", thus:

[image: IME in TextEdit]

However, the title of your question implies that you do not want to use that text editor. However, TextEdit is a system wide text entry mechanism so that particular functionality should be available in a number of text entry fields across the system.

**Evernote** has an autocomplete system, that [relies on the the MAcOS autocomplete](https://discussion.evernote.com/topic/46605-how-do-i-disable-autocomplete/).

There is another method, using **[Emacs](http://emacsformacosx.com/)**, which has an autocompletion mechanism. Again, though, it is tied to use within one particular application, although it is an extremely versatile application, if a little tricky to learn to use.

So, in summary, there appears to be no system-wide IME type functionality, apart rom the one built into OS X's TextEdit mechanism. To re-iterate the answer from Super User: you will have to type in a specific *IME friendly* application and then paste into your application of choice

Comment: Using Evernote is my blind spot.Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try Sogou Pinyin, which is a Chinese input method but also has English mode with auto-completion feature

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I developed an English Input Method for macOS.

[image]

https://pan.baidu.com/s/1jIxckfW
Download the pkg file and install it.

http://blog.csdn.net/lwl_ls/article/details/8564940

version 1.3:

-input freely in any application of macOS.

-select automatically completed words by number.

-select the first suggested word with the Space key.

-enter the characters you typed with the Enter key. (E.G. "bea" in the example)

-remember user words automatically.

-support input space character automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an [input tool](https://github.com/dongyuwei/hallelujahIM) with autocompletion and spell-check feature, and instant translation (to Chinese, but you can replace the dictionary to let it translate English to Japanese) feature.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Please note that whenever you link to your own product, you must explicitly state so as per the [help center](/help/promotion).